# Conv network gets worse when using more data

Tags: modeling, conv-neural-network, image-processing

I'm trying to train a car image classifier based on a smaller version of AlexNet.

I'm trying to learn about conv nets and training models in general, and I've found something that, to me, seems contradictory, so I thought I would put the question up here.

I've initially trained the model with two datasets specific to cars. I got around 99% accuracy both on the validation data-set and training data-set. I then tested the model on a video with marked parking spaces and it mostly identified correctly the occupied parking spaces. However, there was some flickering, as in momentarily giving the wrong classification. Also, when cars were moving in and out of spots, the classification was a bit unstable.

Trying to further tune my model to resolve the above issues, I tried adding more data to the training and validation datasets. I added the COCO dataset which roughly doubled my dataset. I made sure to correctly crop the images of vehicles, adding these to the positive class and the others to the negative class. I also balanced the number of samples in each class by upsampling the positive class samples (horizontal flip) and randomly deleting some samples from the negative class. With this second model I got up to 96% accuracy on the validation dataset, but when testing with the video, it said all spots where vacant, with some momentary flickering to occupied, even though most marked spots where occupied .

How does adding more data make the model perform worse on the video, even though the accuracy percentage seems to remain pretty much the same?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a case of distribution shift to me. Basically, your test data should be drawn from the same distribution as your train data so that you can learn a model that generalizes well. Since you add the COCO dataset to your train set, your model now learns the overall image distribution, which may or may not generalize to your test set. If your video isn't drawn from this distribution, you could get the mixed results that you're describing.

How does one combat this? It might be time to physically take a look at your input images and see if you can identify differences in your original dataset and your dataset with COCO. Then you can ask — are those differences able to be dealt with via some sort of normalization? Would further image augmentation (color shifting, etc.) help?

As further feedback — your data augmentation/balancing techniques seem fine to me.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. COCO images of cars, together with the previous existing dataset and the input images all seem similar to me. 
I resolved the problem by just upsampling the original dataset and converting all images to grayscale. Conveniently, the model's performance increased since now there is only 1 channel instead of 3.